# Laravel Nova: Replace home route and run as default application

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm playing around with Laravel Nova and considering using it in my application. I was wondering if there is a way to make Nova the default application that loads when I hit the URL i.e. instead of navigating to `myapplication.test/nova`, I want the nova dashboard to load when I hit `myapplication.test`. How do I set Laravel `home` route as the 'nova' dashboard?

**Update 1**: I came across this https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/174 but, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: why don't you  use redirect?

Comment: You mean something like return `redirect('/nova')` for the `home` route? I don't want to see the `/nova` in the URL path.

Answer (score 9):

Update Nova Path in `config/nova.php` as `'path' => '/'`

Comment: Make sure you remove other routes to '/'

Answer (score 3):

If you use Nova with a version under 4 can visit this issue [Link](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2098)

If use Nova version 4 all you need to do in (NovaServiceProvider)
override boot function add this line

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Nova::$initialPath = '/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **remove** the code bellow from `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And update Nova Path in `config/nova.php` to `'path' => '/'`

Answer (score 0):

I only know Nova 4, but using all the answers will get what you want plus more.

Update Nova Path in `config/nova.php` as `'path' => '/'` but if you do change it to `'/'` then you will need to **remove** the code bellow from `routes/web.php`

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The default landing page once logged into Nova is `$initialPath = '/dashboards/main';` (src/Nova.php) so if you want to override it then add this to NovaServiceProvider.php

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Nova::$initialPath = '/';
}
```

The docs are correct when they say Nova is heavily configurable, just the docs don't show you how. You have to dig into the codebase.